# How to use " to" in sentences

Tags: grammar

> Foreigners should adapt **to** the local customs when they come **to** reside in a new country.

I want to know the role of **"to"** in this case, how to apply them to the similar sentences, give me more examples.

Comment: Look up "preposition".

Comment: *give me more examples*  Since it's such a common word, and the usage you show is so common too, any well-written text in English on the Internet is likely to provide many many examples.  You could do worse than start with popular English-anguage newspapers' websites.